# Equation of Tangent Plane parallel to another plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Find equation of tangent plane to $$x=(3+2\cos u)\cos v, \space y=x=(3+2 \cos u)\sin v, \space z=2\sin u$$ which is parallel to the plane $x+y+\sqrt{2}z+5=0$. From the equation of the given plane, the normal is $N=(1,1,\sqrt{2})$. So the normal of the tangent plane must be parallel to the tangent plane. But I dont know what I have to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))$ where the coordinate functions are as you described above. For a small open set $U$ about $(u,v)$, we have that $F(U)$ is an orintable surface patch. The tangent plane at $F(u,v)$ is the tangent space $T_{F(u,v)} F(U) = \textbf{im}(D_{(u,v)}F)$, where $D_{(u,v)}F$ is the linear map on the tangent spaces. (See image below)

$$D_{(u,v)}F: T_{(u,v)}U \to T_{F(u,v)} F(U)$$ [image]

For this plane to be parallel to $x+y+\sqrt{2}z = -5$, we need the the normal vector $\textbf{N}$ at $F(u,v)$ to be a multiple of $(1,1,\sqrt{2})$. Here you can take $\textbf{N}_p = F_u(p) \times F_v(p)$, where $p \in U$.

Comment: I do not understand the method you explain. Can you please explain it in an easy way?

Comment: Umm. Plug in a specific $(u,v)$ into your coordinate functions to get a point on the object described by the equations. So lets say this point is $p$. Now to get a tangent plane at $p$, we need $(x,y,z),N$ such that $((x,y,z) - p) \cdot N = 0$, where $N$ is the normal vector. We also need $N = \lambda(1,1,\sqrt{2})$. What I'm saying is that to get $N$, we can use $F_u \times F_v$ which is a normal vector at $F(u,v) = p$. And so get a normal with both requirements by choosing $q$ such that $F_u(q) \times F_v(q) = \lambda (1,1,\sqrt{2})$

Comment: The method I explained was using terminology from differential geometry, which is in correspondence to the tag. I'll edit it to include multivariable calculus as well.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Nice drawing! How did you do it (what software)?

Comment: ok then $(-4\cos v \cos^2u-6\cos v\cos u)i+(-4\sin v\cos^2u-6\sin v\cos u)j+(-4\cos u \sin u-6\sin u)k=\lambda(1,1,\sqrt{2}) $ 
Now what will I do?

Comment: @Kuifje: I'm sorry to say, but it's a screenshot.

Comment: @hitman: Ok, so now you know the first two coordinates of the vector which resulted in the cross product, must be equal.

Comment: So this gives me $\cos v = \sin v$ which means $v=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: also $u=2\pi n +\pi$ or $u=2\pi n -\pi$

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Is it correct now ?

Comment: Okay and $\sin (2\pi n \pm \pi) = \sin (\pm\pi)$ and $\cos(2\pi n \pm \pi) = \cos(\pm \pi) = \cos(\pi)$. Hence, you have your point(s). Now plug it into $F_u \times F_v = N$ and plug that into $((x,y,z) - p) \not N = 0$ and solve.